# How can I conditionally send props depending on parent element?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a component called ListLayout which is a child component for two parent components. I want to pass props based on whichever page is being rendered. Is it possible?

The ListLayout component is as follows;

```
export default function ListLayout(props) {
    return (
    <div>
    <TabNavigation (conditionally accept here based on page being rendered) />
    </div>
}
```

Two parent components send props to ListLayout.

Comment: How do you know what page is being rendered?

Comment: You can pass a prop to `ListLayout` that tells him what's being rendered

Comment: @0stone0 based on the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```html
export default function ListLayout(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <TabNavigation pageData={props.pageOne ? 'send page one' : 'send page two'} />
    </div>
  )
}
```